# Wordpress , local anchor instead of full link with wp_nav_menu

Tags: wordpress, preg-replace, delimiter, wp-nav-menu-item

I'm trying to change the href to a local anchor. My idea was to use preg_replace to strip the home_url();

Instead of....

```
<a href="http://example.com/menu-item/">Menu Item</a>
```

...I'd like to create

```
<a href="#menu-item/">Menu Item</a>
```

My code so far:

```
$menu_one = wp_nav_menu(
array(
    'echo' => 0,
    'container' => false,
    'menu_class' => '',
    'menu_id' => '',
    'theme_location' => 'main-menu'
    )
);

//get home url
$homeurl = home_url();

$menu_one = preg_replace( $homeurl, '#', $menu_one );
echo '<ul id="main-menu">' . $menu_one . '</ul>';
```

I currently get the error preg_replace():
Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash; Any help would be appreciated (my php knowledge is quite limited and also maybe there is a more elegant way to do this)

Comment: You create custom Links in admin-menu.

Comment: @vel Thanks, but I prefer that links are getting created automatically

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your `$homeurl` into a valid regex pattern by wrapping it in a delimiter like `/$homeurl/`.

Also, it is vital to escape some of the characters in the URL.

```php
// Some characters must be "escaped" e.g the / must become \/.
$homeurl = preg_quote( $homeurl );

// Wrap the string in a delimiter that preg_replace expects:
$homeurl = "/$homeurl/";

// Now try it:
$menu_one = preg_replace( $homeurl, '#', $menu_one );
```

Comment: Thank you! I needed to replace the dash delimiter with another delimiter to make it work (I assume  the problem is that the dash is part of the url). I used $homeurl = "[$homeurl]"; instead. However, now when I echo the $homeurl the variable is still wrapped in dashes and it looks like this : <a href="#/theurl/">Link</a>

Comment: @user915308 escaping the URL with `preg_quote` allows you to use the standard `/` (forward slash) delimiter. Please share the pattern you are using :)